# Math within a SQL query - Adding 'results' to display new 'results'

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with thousands of entries, one for each person for each day they worked.  One of the columns is tracking the number of phone calls the person received for that day.  I am using the following query:

```
SELECT [agtName], [contactPhoneCnt] 
FROM [fnDynamicCSCAgtFctByMth] ('09/24/2012','11/07/2012') 
WHERE acct_mo_n = 'October' 
ORDER BY agtName desc
```

This gives me 3822 results.  Results 1-18 are all for a single person (again, one for each day they worked).  What I'd like to do is have the SQL query **add results** 1-18 **from the 'contactPhoneCnt' column and display a single result** instead of 18 individual results.  It is not guaranteed that there will be 18 results... One person might work 10 days during October while another person works 21.  All I care about is getting the total number of calls that person received for the entire month (instead of day by day in individual results).

How would I write the query so it is adding all the entries from a single person and returning a single result for each so I end up with something like 168 results instead of 3822?

Comment: Seems like you want `GROUP BY`

Comment: Provide the table schema if you want additional assistance. We cannot give you an example of a solution without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple group by should do the trick:

```
SELECT  [agtName]
,       count(*)
FROM    fnDynamicCSCAgtFctByMth('09/24/2012','11/07/2012') 
WHERE   acct_mo_n = 'October' 
group by 
        agtName
order by 
        agtName desc
```

Comment: That seemed to group them together so I am only seeing one entry per person, but it did not add together the entries from the 'contactPhoneCnt' column so my results show something like:

"fName.lName   18"  where it should be something like "fName.lName  112"

Comment: @Nicolai, it sounds like you want `Sum(contactPhoneCnt)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: Running this with 'Sum(contactPhoneCnt)' did the trick!  Thanks Andomar and Dour!!

For future reference, where can I get a list of math functions like that 'Sum(columnName)'?

Comment: They're called aggregate functions, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213243%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx